# Get actual URL of file in Moodle using file API

Tags: php, file, moodle

**Intro:**
In moodle we need to create a question (lets say multiple choice question with 4 options) with images in it (in question text or answer text). We are able to put images in question text as well as answer text and moodle displays those images perfectly using its file API.

**Problem:**
My problem is that, i am developing a custom module for printing a quiz, and there I am unable to display those images.

**Details:**
When moodle saves those question and answers in database it saves images URLs in following format (see src attribute of img):

```
<p><img src="@@PLUGINFILE@@/22-2-16.png" alt="" width="1366" height="768" role="presentation" style="vertical-align:text-bottom; margin: 0 .5em;" class="img-responsive"><br></p>
```

Because of moodle's this format, my images are not being fetched. And I need to somehow decode this src attribute to get the actual URL of the images being saved in the database.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you trace through the original question code, starting in question/questionbase.php, you should find a function question_definition::format_text(). This function covers everything you need to do to the question text to prepare it for display.

Internally, it calls question_attempt::rewrite_pluginfile_urls(), which, in turn, calls the function question_rewrite_question_urls() (in lib/questionlib.php). Finally, this drops down into the standard file_rewrite_pluginfile_urls(), to do the job of replacing the '@@PLUGINFILE@@' links in the text.

Hopefully that should be enough to get you started.